# call third fragment in viewpager from first fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have seven fragments implemented through fragmentpageradapter.

I can call second fragment from first fragment sucessfully , but when calling third or fourth fragment from first fragment , i get NullPointerExcpetion when using that fragments functions.

I can only consecutive fragments , and not other fragments .

Comment: Sounds like your later fragments are either on the back stack or garbage collected when you are calling them. If you are calling their methods, those should be offloaded to the activity or helper classes. If you are just trying to bring them back on the screen, you should be calling them through an interface in the activity which should be checking if they are null/on the back stack. In other words, your fragments shouldn't directly communicate.

Comment: In the future you should post your code.

Comment: ok , but i thought of it as a general question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is **you can't**. Pager Adapter loads only 3 fragments at one time - the rest isn't waiting for you in the memory.

So you must store your changes and apply them as you change the current fragment later.

Comment: Actually you can do `myPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(someInt)` to override that.

Comment: Oh, thanks. It seems I'm not ready to answer questions yet :).

Comment: There will always be someone who knows more. I am shown up here daily. Incidentally, you don't always want to set a high page limit as lots of fragments in memory equals slow app.

Comment: so , just doing myPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(someInt) , would get my pager adapter to load all my fragments at one time , and so i could call my nth fragment methods from my first fragment

Comment: ok , so `myPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(someInt)` , did the trick , i know it's not a good solution , as it makes the app slow , but anyways it works for me  ,i am not dealing with a heavy app